# How to ensure multiple Bot Builder V4 bot instances process one user message at a time?

Tags: botframework

We're deploying a chat bot across multiple servers. If a user sends 2 messages that hit different servers, I want to make sure the messages are processed in order and one at a time. In V3, I was able to implement a custom [IScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.internals.fibers.iscope-1?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0) class to support this behavior, backed by Redis and [RedLock.net](https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net). How does this work in V4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotnet Bot Builder SDK V4 does not provide a mechanism internally enabling pessimistic locking or ensuring messages are processed in order.  However, it is likely that you could utilize your Redis lease implementation within the OnTurn of a V4 bot.

We do provide a scale out sample here: [42. Scale Out](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/42.scaleout)  But, it uses an ETag optimistic locking strategy that does not ensure message processing order.

Another option might be to use Service Bus with a [Queue Based Load Leveling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/queue-based-load-leveling) strategy in front of the bot.